# Запрос внутри запроса typeorm postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise, typeorm

Есть сущность `Card`, у которой я бы хотел сохранять очередность. Просто по `id` не получится, т.к. у каждого пользователя свои приватные `Card`, так что я пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное:

```
      await Card.find({where: {userId: payload.userId}}).then(data => {
        Card.insert({
          name: name,
          order: data.slice(-1).order,
          userId: payload.userId
        })
      })
```

То есть, я при добавлении `Card` в БД хочу сначала получить последний добавленный `Card`, узнать его `order` и добавить новый `Card` с `order + 1`.

Как правильно получить данные из одного промиса и передать в другой? Или быть может в typeorm есть получше способы реализации подобного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же уже пишите "ждать до получения результата", то есть `await`

```js
const card = await Card.find({where: {userId: payload.userId}});
if (card !== null) {
    Card.insert({
        name: name,
        order: card.slice(-1).order,
        userId: payload.userId
    });
}
```